# Are there Canadians who actually spell "organiSe, organiSation" "recogniSe" "realiSe" "authoriSe" with an S instead of a Z?

Tags: orthography, canadian-english

I've been noticing that some of my fellow Canadians habitually spell words such as "organise, organisation" "realise" recognise""authorise" instead "organize, organization" "realize" "recognize" "authorize." I've been told by other Canadians that Canadians use -ise and -ize interchangeably; both are considered correct as long as you choose one and be consistent. But that puzzles me because according to all Canadian dictionaries that I've looked at, the -ize spelling is prescribed. I thought the -ise would appear as a minor variant, but it doesn't appear at all in any Canadian dictionary. My question is: is the -ise really an acceptable variant in Canadian English? or is the -ize mandatory like in the US?

Comment: *is the -ize mandatory like in the US?* Who mandates it?  I understand that it is customary in US English to use *-ize* where many British would use *-ise* but who mandates it?

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. I notice you haven't completed the [Tour] and suggest that you do that as this SE lists are a little different from others. If you a look at the Help on Asking Good Questions you will see that we expect posters to do some research themselves. You might do an internet search for these words in specifically Canadian publications — newspapers and the like — to see if the practice is different from what the dictionaries prescribe, as that is your interest. Anecdotal answers from individuals are not really useful.

Comment: Hi Steven! You might find these sites helpful. [The Canadian Style](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=eng&lettr=indx245&info0=3.16) and [The Remedy of Errors](https://www.theremedyoferrors.com/blog/2017/3/28/the-remedy-of-errors-ise-or-ize).

Answer (score 1):

Margery Fee & Janice McAlpine, *[Oxford] Guide to Canadian English Usage*, second edition (2007) offers this discussion of *-ize* versus *-ise* verb endings in Canadian English:

> **-ize, -ise, -yze, -yse** Where there is a choice between *-ize* and *-ise* Canadian writers, kike Americans, tend to to choose the endings with *z*. In fact, Canadian, American, and British writers all prefer *-ize* for *recognize*, *civilize* and *civilization*, *organize* and *organization*, *realize* and *realization*, and specialize and specialization. The British preference for *-ise* endings is an innovation rather than a longstanding spelling tradition. **In Canada and Britain either spelling is usually considered correct**, while in the United States the *-ize* endings are de rigueur.
>
> Note, however, that Canadian, American, and British writers all use *-ise* for *advertise*, *supervise*, and *surprise*. For these words, the spelling with *z* is not an option.

So, according to Fee & McAlpine, some Canadians (and some British people) do use *-ise* endings for many words that most people in the United States would spell with an *-ize* ending.

Comment: I think we've had stats here before indicating that (and some British people) should be (and 65% of British people).